# Expose a rest api to communicate using Json

Tags: .net, rest, json.net, getjson

I am tring to find out a rest api which can accept values in JSON format and response also in the same format.

Need to know how to code it through .NET technology.

Hoe to send and receive values and response.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Asp.Net Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) - there's lots of good walkthroughs and guides on the site linked.